# jQuery daterange picker autoclose false not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using jquery date rangepicker. while i select date from daterange picker i don't want to close the calendar. so i use this code. but it's not working. can any one help. please. here is my code

```
<div class="form">
    <input id="d" class="form__daterange">
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.daterange.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#d").daterange({
        numberOfMonths: 12,
        minView: 2,
        autoclose: false,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "it's not working" is a waste of words. Be more specific.

Comment: just look at your console it will show you what's wrong as per my thinking daterange()  you need to change or modify

Answer (score 1):

you need autoClose: false

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#d").daterange({
    numberOfMonths: 12,
    minView: 2,
    autoClose: false,
    });
});
```

Comment: C is capital in autoClose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

or modify yours like

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#d").datepicker({

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's a different library

Comment: daterange is not a function he need to use datepicker()

Comment: It's look like he has copied jQuery files and using them as local by changing just a name so it giving him problem that is why i said daterange() is not function

Comment: Looks like he is using another plugin that provides that function and is not trying to use the Jquery UI API. As for not a function, it's impossible to say because he doesn't say what is wrong just that it doesn't work...

Comment: @Aluan Haddad okay I am agree with you :)